# how do i add a style to a single items border in a datalist in asp.net from code behind? (i want a single border color to be different)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datalist, web-controls

this what my datalist looks like [this is the datalist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NvXr.png)

[this is the code behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tp2f.png)

I tried to cast the table of the HTML as a web control table and then access it style from code behind and change it like I did with the buttons the problem is that the table border wont change

Answer (score 0):

you should set the atribute `runat="server"` to the item you want to change from code behind.

and in the code behind yo can try something like this:

```
label4.Attributes.Add('bgcolor', 'red');
```

where labe4 is the id of the element you want to change

Comment: the element i want to change is within a datalist I can just access it like this because there is a x number of elements like this displayed within 1 datalist.

Answer (score 0):

You as a general rule can use the row data bound event.

Say this markup:

```
   <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div id="myrow" runat="server" style="border-style:solid;color:black;width:300px;">
        <div style="padding:5px;text-align:right">
            <p>Hotel Name: <asp:TextBox ID="HotelName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></p>
            <p>First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></p>
            <p>Last Name: <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'    /></p>
            <p>City: <asp:TextBox ID="City" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("City") %>'  /></p>
            <p>Province: <asp:TextBox ID="Province" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("Province") %>'  /></p>
            Active: <asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server" Checked = '<%# Eval("Active") %>'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

And now code behind can look like this:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();

    void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT top 10 * from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                DataList1.DataSource = rstData;
                DataList1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And data bound, we can use for formatting any control/text box. Say turn City red for city = "Edmonton"

We have this:

```
    protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item){

            TextBox txtCity = e.Item.FindControl("City") as TextBox;
            if (txtCity.Text == "Edmonton")
            {
                // set border as red
                txtCity.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("red");
            }

        }
    }
```

results:

[image]